# CAKE: Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, .net, cakebuild

I use CAKE 0.21.1.0.

In my CAKE script, I added the following directive:

```
#r @"\\hostName\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Some.Local.Project.dll"
```

When running the script, I see this error:

[image]

As far as I can see, there is no difference between what I am doing and what the [CAKE documentation](https://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives) recommends.

I know that the `#r` directive is the cause of the error, because everything runs fine after I comment out that line as well as all those lines that call its library methods.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Maybe take alook at flubu which is a nice alternative to cake more at: https://github.com/flubu-core/flubu.core/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `@` sign, and use forward slashes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As a follow-up question, how can I specify that I'd like to load that assembly in an unsafe manner using the ``#r`` directive?

Comment: @MY_G sorry, no idea - I never used Cakebuild, just figured out the original problem with a quick look at the linked docs.